# Databinding + Gradle related issues with Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci, android-studio-2.3

After I updated my Android Studio to v2.3.3 and with it updated the required build tools and sdk version, have been getting the following error when I run `./gradlew assemble --stacktrace`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':OpenEdXMobile'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':OpenEdXMobile:_prodDebugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.pom
>            file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.jar
>            file:/home/travis/build/edx/edx-app-android/sdk-manager/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :OpenEdXMobile
>   Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.pom
>            file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.jar
>            file:/home/travis/build/edx/edx-app-android/sdk-manager/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.3/baseLibrary-2.3.3.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :OpenEdXMobile > com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
>            project :OpenEdXMobile > com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1

Full report from **Travis-CI** can be [found here](https://travis-ci.org/edx/edx-app-android/builds/252347067?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification).

Here are some relevant details:

The gradle's distribution url: `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Gradle version in my module's build.gradle is `v2.3.3`.

My full `build.gradle` is kinda big so here's the link to it.
https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android/blob/f899aeca945dea9a010af727e2b3ff1176e86f4e/build.gradle

**Do mention if I have missed any details :)**

Comment: Do you resolve this?

Comment: Sadly no :(
I just had to downgrade my gradle version to v2.3.0 and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I had to do the same.

Comment: @Dom would be great if you upvote this question, so that someone might be able to give a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I wasn't able to find a solution that worked with the settings and versions mentioned in the question.

**Quick Fix:**
I just had to downgrade my gradle version to v2.3.0 and everything worked just fine.

**Future plan:**
Will update this answer once I find a solution, for now I've mentioned the quick fix, so that the community can benefit.